# Insert data into influxdb from node / windows causes problems

Tags: node.js, windows, influxdb, carriage-return

I'm trying to insert data into InfluxDb using node/windows but there is a (seemingly well-know) bug that I am having trouble wrapping my mind around. I am trying to do a batch insert into my local db by loading data from a file and sending to my database using a POST. Here is the data that I am trying to insert:

test_data.txt

```
test_measurement test=val1 1516665684
test_measurement price=val2 1516665685
test_measurement price=val3 1516665686
```

Using the code:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile('test_data.txt', { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err, data) {
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "localhost",
    "port": "8086",
    "path": "/write?db=test_db",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      console.log(body.toString());
    });
  });

  req.write(data);
  req.end();
});
```

And I get the error

```
{"error":"unable to parse 'test_measurement test=val1 1516665684\r': bad timestamp\nunable to parse 'test_measurement price=val2 1516665685\r': bad timestamp\nunable to parse 'test_measurement price=val3 1516665686': bad timestamp"}
```

From my research, I understand that windows uses \r\n characters as a carriage return, but I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around how to fix this. I've made attempts to remove all \r and \n characters when I read the file in, but it doesn't seem to remove them, as I continue to get the same error. Even if I was able to remove them this way, how would influx know where the next insert of the batch began? It needs to know where the next line starts for a batch insert, but doesn't like the new line characters.

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Double quote string field values. Do not double quote floats, integers, or booleans.](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/#quoting)

UPDATE (after the actual response appears there in description)

Then it apparently `\r`.

Your file were created by Windows editor, I presume - that's it got both symbols at the end.

So you just turn it into Unix format, there are pleny of tools for it, perhaps, Notepad++ is most popular.

Or, better off, just add some humble string pre-processing into your code, it's supereasy with JS:

```
req.write(data.replace("\r",""));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've read the link and i'm not sure how it applies to the situation. It says never quote a timestamp, measurement, field key, or field value as a float, none of which I am doing. Maybe you were referring to the line: "InfluxDB will ignore all subsequent characters until the next newline \n"?

I've tried to remove all carriage returns in my document and separate lines with a \n, but I then get an error saying 1516665684\\n 'bad timestamp'.

Comment: My bad!! I just realized that the error message I posted said 'invalid boolean' but the actual error message is 'bad timestamp' due to 1516665684\r not being a timestamp. Fixed the original question error message -_

Comment: yet it is looks unrealistic that string field value ever pass without doublequotes

Comment: got it resolved! parsing out the '\r' in my node did the trick. thanks.